# OpenCV Camera display bug

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

The Camera on my galaxy s2(Android 4.4.2) looks like this when i run the color blob sample code. The same code works on my galaxy tab 2 (also Android 4.4.2).

Tried with writing the code from scratch and other sample codes. There are no errors on both devices, but the image looks like this on the S2

Does anybody know how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Interesting, are you using the latest OpenCV? Does it happen with all its official samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same result running OpenCV Samples on my S2 i9100 with Neatrom 3.6 (4.4.2) and ART enabled. Changing ART back to Dalvik does not change anything (for what it`s worth).
Using Stock Samsung Rom fixes the problem. Seems to be something in the Custom Rom which causes the problem.

After some testing this seems to be the only working Rom for me.
I checked without success the following Roms:

- CyanogenMod 10.1
- CyanogenMod 10.2
- CyanogenMod 11
- SlimSaber 4.4.2
- Biftor™SlimKat-Rom-V6.0-i9100-4.4.2
- I9100_4.4.2_AOSP_NeatROM_v3.6
- SlimBean 4.2.2

Comment: Is this the only way to fix it?